# New Python 3.1 does not recognize a simple variable?

Tags: python, pycharm

So, basically I updated my old Python 2.7 version to Python 3.1 and now I face a problem in one of my Projects I made, so apparently variables I made in my old Python version were recognized from Python (`guess_taken` and `number`) but I wanted to add a variable `points` like this `points = 0` but for some reason PyCharm won't recognize it. Does anyone know a solution to this?

Here is the code:

[image]

Comment: Python *3.1*? The most recent version is 3.8. You should really update to something newer.

Comment: What do you mean by "recognize it?" If you're talking about the greyed out font, I'm guessing that is supposed to indicate that you don't use the variable anywhere (and hence it is superfluous).

Comment: I do use it below in my code but it does not change anything..

Comment: @dzonny Update to 3.8 as mentioned above. If the problem still persists, update this questions and reply in the comment section. It is really hard to say, because a parsing error in one location can throw off PyCharm in other locations when parsing.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely you have not used the variable anywhere, PyCharm greys out variable which it thinks are useless. Try using it somewhere, so that PyCharm knows it is not useless

If this is the case then go to the variable; press Alt+enter and it will suggest something along the lines of safely remove variable because it considers it redundant.

I don't have PyCharm right now but IntelliJ IDEA with the python plugin shows the same color hint.

[image: hinting]

**EDIT**

[image: fix]

Comment: Thanks, i fixed this problem by only updating a Python to a newer version.

Comment: it is not related to python version, it is the hint provided by PyCharm.